# Fourier transform of $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4} n)$

Tags: fourier-transform

$x(n)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}n)$

$X(v)=\frac{1}{2j}\delta(v-\frac{1}{8})-\frac{1}{2j}\delta(v+\frac{1}{8})$ ?

Is this result correct?

Comment: It depends on the definition of Fourier Transform you are given (there are at least three different ones).

Comment: By $j$ do you mean $\sqrt{-1}\text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Any work to provide, as well as the convention of Fourier Transform ?

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes, what do you mean by convention of Fourier Transform?

Comment: By convention, he means the definition: is Fourier Transform $ A \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}exp(- 2 \pi j nt)f(t)dt$ for you ? With which coefficient $A$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, without the A coefficient

Answer (score -1):

We know that Fourier Transform of $\dfrac{1}{2\pi}$ is $\sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^\infty\delta(v-2\pi k)$, i.e. 
\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\left(\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\right)&=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\delta(v-2\pi k)\\
\implies\mathscr{F}(1)&=\pi\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\delta(v-2\pi k)\\
\implies\mathscr{F}\left(1\cdot e^{jv_0n}\right)&=2\pi\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\delta(v-v_0-2\pi k)\\
\implies\mathscr{F}\left(e^{jv_0n}\right)&=2\pi\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\delta(v-v_0-2\pi k)\\
\end{align}
Now,
\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\left[\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} n\right)\right]&=\dfrac{1}{2j}\mathscr{F}\left[e^{j\frac{\pi}{4}n}-e^{-j\frac{\pi}{4}n}\right]\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2j}\left[2\pi\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\delta(v-\frac{\pi}{4}-2\pi k)-2\pi\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\delta(v+\frac{\pi}{4}-2\pi k)\right]\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{j}\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty\left[\delta(v-\frac{\pi}{4}-2\pi k)-\delta(v+\frac{\pi}{4}-2\pi k)\right]
\end{align}

Comment: Why are you messing up with a Dirac comb ? The OP didn't mean that obviously

Comment: you wrote the object in terms of deltas. You need to write it in terms of sin(kx)'s!